# How to split a single list item into multiple items

Tags: python

I have a input list1 like this. I want to convert the list1 into list2 with the below specified format.
Can anyone please let me know whether we have an option in python to convert using list method**(without converting the input list into string format)** ?

```
list1 = ['a1 a2 a3 a4 a5']
list2 = ['a1, a2, a3, a4, a5']
```

Expected Output:

```
list1[0] = ['a1 a2 a3 a4 a5']
list2[0] = a1
list2[1] = a2
```

Comment: Does your `list1` contain 5 elements or 1 element?  Do you want your `list2` to contain 5 elements or 1 element?

Comment: have you tried `list2 = list1[0].split()` ? However, the way you typed `list2` is not coherent with your Expected Output. Your Expected Output requires `list2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']`

Comment: Your second list still contains one item, a string, and your expected output for `list2[0]` is nothing valid - do you expect the string 'a1'? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a1 a2 a3 a4 a5']
list2 = [x.split(' ') for x in list1][0]
list2
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```

Comment: It would help to add at least a short explanation of how this code works. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers By the way, if you write `.split()` instead of `.split(' ')`, it will split on any sequence of whitespace and ignore whitespace at the start and end of the string, which is usually more useful.

Comment: There's no need for list comprehension here as there is only 1 item in the iterable and you end up only taking the first item from the resulting list.

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
list2 = [item.strip() for item in 'a1, a2, a3, a4, a5'.split(',')]

# list2 becomes: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```

Edit:

Re-reading the issue, if you are looking to convert list1 into list2 with the expected output. However it is not totally clear what you are looking for.

```
list2 = list1[0].split()

# list2 becomes: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```